# Can't convert circle to asterisks (*)

Tags: react-native

Here Is My Password View.

```
 <LinearGradient
         colors={focused2?['#FF53C0', '#FF53C000', '#FF53C000']:['#60FFCA', '#60FFCA00', '#60FFCA00']}
        start={{x: 0.6, y: 0}}
        end={{x: 1, y: 0.8}}
        style={styles.PasswordLinearGradient}>
        <View style={styles.PasswordView}>
          <Image
            source={focused2?require('../assets/images/Password_Pink.png'):require('../assets/images/PasswordIcon.png')}
            style={styles.PasswordLogo}></Image>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Password"
            ref={ref_input1}
            onFocus={handleFocus2}
            onBlur={handleBlur2}  
           onChangeText={text=>setPassword(text)}
            //secureTextEntry={!showPassword}
            value={!showPassword?password:'*'.repeat(password.length)} // This is important.
            placeholderTextColor={'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)'}
            style={styles.EmailTextInput}></TextInput>
          {focused2==true?
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>togglePassword()}>
              <Image
                source={!showPassword?require('../assets/images/Show_Password_Pink.png'):require('../assets/images/Hide_Password_Pink.png')}
                style={styles.HidePasswordLogo}></Image>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          :
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>togglePassword()}>
              <Image
                source={!showPassword?require('../assets/images/Show_Password.png'):require('../assets/images/Hide_Password.png')}
                style={styles.HidePasswordLogo}></Image>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          }
        </View>
      </LinearGradient>
```

i want when i click to hide button so show asterrisks and then click to the show password so show character.
i stuck when my button is hide and i write some character and then show not see properly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want by default in text input field secure text entry show a circle but i want when i toggle my password and my state varibale is false then show ****** when  my state variable is true so show my password like (ex:brijesh123) like that i want

Answer (score 0):

Here is the minimal example using [secureTextEntry](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#securetextentry).

```js
const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
const [secure, setSecure] = React.useState(true);

<TextInput
  value={password}
  onChangeText={setPassword}
  secureTextEntry={secure}
/>
<Pressable onPress={() => setSecure((value) => !value)}>
  <Text>{secure ? 'Show' : 'Hide'}</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Comment: But My Problem Is not Like You Understand, I want When i Write some Charcter So Secure text entry By Default is Circle i want it chnages to the ******* like that.\